# MathJax in titles: Can we give users a warning prompt (or an error prompt) when they try this?

Tags: discussion, formatting

There's many reasons not to use MathJax in our titles: [MathJax or Unicode in titles? Does it matter? (pun intended)](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/189/5)

Ask yourself why Stack Exchange immediately disqualifies all questions with MathJax in the title, from appearing in the HNQ list, despite the vast majority of the questions on some of SE's biggest sites, having MathJax in the titles. There's reasons to not have MathJax in titles.

<s>It's unlikely that we'll be able to "selectively" enable MathJax for title and not for non-titles, because of the way MathJax is called in an `.html` file (as far as I know). However, When a user puts two `$` signs in a title on this site, I'm quite certain that it means only one thing: MathJax. When two `$` signs are detected, **I propose that we don't let the question be posted as is** (error message) or at least that the user gets prompted to click a box saying whether or not they have successfully removed all MathJax in the title (warning message).</s>

[This comment by Rydwolf Programs](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/mathjax-in-titles-can-we-give-users-a-warning-prompt-or-an-error-prompt-when#comment772_340) suggests that SE would be able to disallow MathJax from titles quite easily.

[This message by kaya3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63698362#63698362) also suggests that it's easy for SE to do.

Comment: I completely agree.

Comment: Note that it is possible to selectively choose where MathJax is allowed, you can pass a list of nodes to `MathJax.typeset`

Comment: @NikeDattani For SE to do, yeah. It _might_ be possible to inject something early enough into the page loading for end-users to do it, but you'd have to change `window.MathJax` before the MathJax script loads (to tell it not to typeset the whole document immediately on page load)